# Grunt task runs but not registered explicitly?

Tags: gruntjs

I've been using Yoeman and Angular for a while, but running the same grunt commands repeatedly meant I never really understood Grunt. Having read [Getting Started on GruntJS.com](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started) I have a question.

My Gruntfile.js registers the following tasks:

`grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {...});
grunt.registerTask('test', function (target) {...});
grunt.registerTask('build', function (target) {...});
grunt.registerTask('default', function (target) {...});`

Yet I can run `grunt clean` and the `clean:dist` tasks runs. If I try and run a nonsensical task, Grunt balks:

`grunt cleanmypants
Warning: Task "cleanmypants" not found. Use --force to continue.`

Clearly `clean` is a Grunt task, but since it's never registered using `grunt.registerTask(...)` - why does it run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have a configured task named `clean` with a sub-task `dist`.

Here is an example :

```js
grunt.config.init({
    clean: {
        dist: {
            src: ["path/to/dir/one", "path/to/dir/two"]
        },
        dev: {
            src: ["path/to/dir/one", "path/to/dir/two"]
        }
    }
});
```

If you run `clean:dist`, you will run only this task, but if you run `clean`, you will run all subtasks (`dist` and `dev`). Then if you search in your files, you should have a file like this.

**There are 2 kind of tasks in Grunt** :

- configured tasks
- registered tasks

Here is a configured task:

```js
grunt.config.init({
  jshint: {
    all: ['lib/*.js', 'test/*.js', 'Gruntfile.js']
  }
});
```

Here is a register task:

```
task.registerTask('JshintRegisterTask', ['jshint', 'concat']);
```

**Registered tasks allow you to create new task with your configured tasks.**

Read Grunt.js documentation for more information :

- [tasks configuration](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.config#initializing-config-data)
- [tasks registration](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#creating-tasks)